# This code does not work with latest jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using some code from http://phpcode.hu/teszt/jquery_select/

**Seemingly I didnt add enough information, hence this question is getting voted down, faster than celine dion singing on the titanic.**

Ok The php code below ( is just for posterity ) all code for this script is included below , nothing more or less - aside from the actual db connection which has bugger all to do with it.

Steps: running this is jquery 1.2.3 the code runs absolutely fine.
Anything after that build and we get zilch in the secondary select field ( **Cities** )

Running in latest jQuery build: using firebug on FF 10.

If we make a state selection, the cities selection does not propagate. However if we inspect the eleemnt we can see only this:

```
<select id="cities" style="min-width:212px;"> </select>
```

But if we run firebug , console:

Params: ajax    true
states  3
Response:
[{optionValue: 4, optionDisplay: 'Canberra'}]
Html:
[{optionValue: 4, optionDisplay: 'Canberra'}]

Issue is it does not work with latest jquery builds, in fact only seems to work with 
jQuery 1.2.3 - New Wave Javascript

So thats not a massive deal, as it uses very very little js. So wondered if you looked at this code, could you see what screams out at you as to why it doesnt operate with latest jquery build ?

```
$(function(){
          $("select#states").change(function(){
            $.getJSON("select.php",{states: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
              var options = '';
              for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
              }
              $("select#cities").html(options);
            })
          })


        })
```

Form:

```
<!-- form to change location-->
                <select id="states" style="min-width:212px;">
                    <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
                    <?php
                    createoptions("states", "states_id", "states");
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    <select id="cities" style="min-width:212px;">
                </select>
            <!--//end-->
```

The php if its any use ( this on the select.php )

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 0);

  include("conndb.php");

  function createoptions($table , $id , $field , $condition_field , $value)
   {
   $sql = sprintf("select * from $table WHERE $condition_field=%d ORDER BY $field" , $value);
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    $out[] = "{optionValue: {$a[$id]}, optionDisplay: '$a[$field]'}";
    return "[" . implode("," , $out) . "]";
  } else

    return "[{optionValue: -1 , optionDisplay: 'No result'}]";
  }

  if (isset($_GET['states'])) {
echo createoptions("cities" , "cities_id" , "cities" , "states_id" , $_GET['states']);
  }


  die();
 ?>
```

Lastyly the php for db connection:

```
<?php
 include("conndb.php");
 function createoptions($table , $id , $field)
 {
$sql = "select * from $table ORDER BY $field";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
echo "<option value=\"{$a[$id]}\">$a[$field]</option>";
}
?>
```

Ive posted almost evertyhing, just in case theses a ISSUE thats screaming off the page

Comment: "Does not work" isn't too helpful -- can you try it with a javascript console open and post any error messages?

Comment: What doesn't work?  What errors do you get?

Comment: "So wondered if you looked at this code, could you see what screams out at you as to why it doesnt operate with latest jquery build" - Not many people are going to comb through your code trying to find something when they don't even know what they're looking for. Debug it yourself and come back with specifics.

Comment: I am assuming jquery selectors have changed, hence why i didnt do a fiddle. Plus its db driven. Works in jquery v i posted, not latest. So just wanted to know if any jquery gurus could spot a faux pas

Comment: Guys try and be constructive, rather than vote down. The issue i am sure is purely jquery related.

Comment: Be constructive?? WE?? Anyway, any error in the console?

Comment: No errors at all. In console, headers http and response is fine. eg. [{optionValue: 2, optionDisplay: 'Brisbane'}] But via page src : inspect same element <select id="cities" style="min-width:212px;"> </select>

Comment: @422 You should edit your post to include that information.  You may want to pare down your code samples to just the parts that are likely to be the problem, and explain what result you are expecting and what result you are instead getting.  On its own, "doesn't work" doesn't mean anything to anyone but you.

Comment: Updated the Q @Farray , hopefully some of the knobs who voted this down, may reconsider. A genuine question hoping for sympathetic replies

Answer (score 6):

This isn't valid JSON:

```
[{optionValue: -1 , optionDisplay: 'No result'}]
```

For it to be valid, it should be:

```
[{"optionValue": -1 , "optionDisplay": "No result"}]
```

JSON may be a sub-set of JavaScript syntax, but it's a **strict** sub-set. It doesn't support the same luxuries like *identifiers as object keys*. [They must be strings](http://json.org/).

To help ensure valid JSON, have a look at PHP's own [JSON functions](http://php.net/json) for object serialization:

```
return json_encode(
    array(
        array("optionValue" => -1, "optionDisplay" => "No result")
    )
);
```

Comment: Thankyou Jonathan , I was hoping it was the jquery/javascript will go check.

Comment: Seemingly the guys jquery needs complete overhaul. The above didnt solve the issue, albeit probably fixed one issue lol.